# How to substract a "y" value from the trendline **numpy and pylab**

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 3 point graph with a trendline but I need to find an "x" value for specific y value. Here is what I have:

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
x = ng
y = density
plt.scatter(x, y)
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,p(x),"r--")
```

[image]

The x value is basically a DNA concentration whereas the y value is a densitometric value that I calculated. I need to find a DNA concertation for the density of 19159.8.
Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: You have the equation of the straight line i.e. `z` or `p`. Therefore, simply plug the value for y (19159.8) into your equation of a straight line (rearranging for x)

Answer (score 1):

The inverse function of `y = a*x + b` is simply `x = (1/a)*y + (-b/a)`:

```py
a, b = z
z_inv = np.array([1 / a, -b / a])
p_inv = np.poly1d(z_inv)
print(np.allclose(p_inv(p(x)), x))
# True
```